# Removing a custom cursor on tumblr

Tags: html, css, cursor, tumblr

I am having a problem with removing a custom cursor on my theme. I am using the theme [Sucy by guroshoujo](http://nekoma.co.vu/post/51060809772/sucy-by-guroshoujo-live-preview-400px-code).

I already removed the cursor code and deleted my cache but it still shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this CSS rule:

```
body { cursor: default !important; }
```

The problem is that you had put the `cursor` property in differents elements (for example, in `div.media > a`). If you add the `!important` you ensure "overwrite" the `cursor` properties of the other elements.

Comment: bruh tf i dont even remember asking this but thank you